# Custom controllers for Manipulate[] in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've created a function test[], which could also be a symbol test, if need be, and I'm trying to implement it in a manipulate. test[] looks like this:

```
test[]:=Button["Label",Functionality[]];
```

This will return an error if used directly in a Manipulate[], but works if it is wrapped in a Dynamic or an Evaluate.

```
Manipulate[content,test[]];
```

> Manipulate::vsform: Manipulate argument test[] does not have the correct form for a variable specification.

```
Manipulate[content,Dynamic[test[]]]
```

This one works

```
Manipulate[content,Evaluate[test]]
```

Note that while this works, test is not a function

```
Manipulate[content,Evaluate[test[]]]
```

This works on my mac, but not my PC at work...

I think the issue is something to do with Manipulate being HoldAll, but don't understand why Dynamic[] should fix this. Also, Evaluate[] will only work some of the time.

So, why is the Dynamic[] or Evaluate[] necessary? Looking under the custom controllers section of the advanced manipulate tutorial, I see no references to this issue, and could not find any elsewhere.

Comment: can you post complete, self contained working code that one can copy and paste? including all the definitions you show there? make a small example that shows the problem. Showing one line from here and there, with symbols that are not defined, makes it hard to help you. I do not see how what you say worked for you can actually work. But you did not show the complete code, so may be there is something else going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can inline the `Button` instead of using a separate `test[]` function.  Otherwise you last example, `Manipulate[content,Evaluate[test[]]]`, *does* show the button on my machine in Mathematica 8.  There should be no difference between platforms (Windows or Mac).

If you're doing something sufficiently different from what `Manipulate` provides by default, you may find it more convenient to build it from scratch using `Dynamic` (this is what I usually do).

---

Here's an example of how to include some buttons as controllers.

First, set up something to show inside the `Manipulate`:

```
rotate90[{x_, y_}] := {-y, x}

koch[p1_, p2_, n_] := {koch[p1, p1 + (p2 - p1)/3, n - 1], 
  koch[p1 + (p2 - p1)/3, (p1 + p2)/2 + Sqrt[3]/6 rotate90[p2 - p1], 
   n - 1], koch[(p1 + p2)/2 + Sqrt[3]/6 rotate90[p2 - p1], 
   p2 - (p2 - p1)/3, n - 1], koch[p2 - (p2 - p1)/3, p2, n - 1]}

koch[p1_, p2_, 0] := Line[{p1, p2}]

snowflake[n_] := 
 Graphics[{koch[{0, 0}, {1, 0}, n], 
   koch[{1, 0}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, n], 
   koch[{1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}, n]}]
```

Then set up the `Manipulate` itself:

```
Manipulate[snowflake[n], {{n, 2}, ControlType -> None}, 
 Style["A Koch snowflake", Bold], Delimiter, 
 Row[{Button["+", n++], Button["-", n = Max[n - 1, 0]]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's an example showing that this works even if the `Button` is defined in a separate function:

```
SetAttributes[paletteButton, HoldRest]
paletteButton[name_, func_] := 
 Button[name, func, Appearance -> "Palette"]

Manipulate[snowflake[n], {{n, 2}, ControlType -> None}, 
 Style["A Koch snowflake", Bold], Delimiter, 
 Evaluate@paletteButton["+", n++]]
```

As you mentioned in your question, here it is necessary to wrap the function in `Evaluate` to obtain an inlined `Button`.  Otherwise `Manipulate` will not be able to notice that what we have here is a *control* and not a *variable*.